# What can I attempt when the derivative tests fail?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The simultaneous equation I got from my Lagrange multiplier has proven itself a masochistic task. I found one trivial solution and I don't give a #### about the rest as they're too hard to find. I tried the second partial derivative test and fun fact. Three of the eigenvalues were 0.  This is the function: $f(a, b, c, d, e) = (a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)-e(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-abcd-5)$

Comment: Did this question arise in some setting that is more meaningful than just an algebraic formula?

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't mentioned what you were being asked about the function, but you mention the second partial-derivative test, I am assuming you were to say something about its maximum and minimum values.

In an academic course, when students are given a problem that looks horribly complicated, they are often being asked to notice something that makes it much simpler.  (This doesn't necessarily apply to real-world problems.)

This is going to be a partial answer.  What we see in the expression for the function is that it is essentially unchanged if we permute the variables $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ c \ , \ $ and $ \ d \ . $  In functions which have this kind of symmetry, the extrema can occur where all of these variables *are equal*, or where *all but one* of them equals zero.

In the first case, for $ \ a = b = c = d \ , $ the expression "collapses" to
$$ (a^2+1)^4 \ - \ e·(6a^2-a^4-5) \ \ = \ \ a^8 \ + \ 4a^6 \ + \ (6+e)a^4 \ + \ (4-6e)a^2 \ + (1+5e) \ \ . $$

I have left $ \ e \ $ as a "free" variable.   We see that it is an even function in $ \ a \ , $ so any solution for $ \ a \ $ has a "mirror" solution $ \ -a \ . $  What is interesting about the behavior of the function is that for $ \ e \ < \ \approx 0.7 \ $ (could it be $ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ $ ? ) , there is only an **absolute minimum** at $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ $ , but for $ \ e \ > \ \approx 0.7 \ , $ this changes to a **local maximum** at $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ $ with a pair of **local minima** at $ \ a \ = \ \pm a_{min} \ $ nearby.

For the other case, with a single non-zero variable, say, $ \ a \ $ , the expression is reduced to $ \ a^2 \ + \ (1+5e) \ , $ which plainly have only an absolute minimum at $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ . $  That just means there is a minimum value $ \ (1+5e) \ $  for the function at the origin for *any* value of $ \ e \ . $

The second-partial derivative test is not always helpful for polynomials with degrees higher than $ \ 2 \ $ ; this one counts as having degree $ \ 8 \ $ .  It looks like the only interesting case is for $ \ e \ > \ 0.7... \ , $ for which local minima occur at points with various combinations of signs for $ \ ( \pm a_{min} \ , \pm a_{min} \ , \pm a_{min} \ , \pm a_{min}) \   $  and a local maximum at the origin.

Without some further context concerning the interpretation of this function or the intention of the problem, it is difficult to say much more. (Perhaps someone else has additional thoughts.)